# How to make a grid inside a cell?

Tags: microsoft-office

Is there any way I can make a grid inside a cell in a table? [Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yaaC.png).

In the shading property of the cell there's a grid pattern, but the grid is really tiny and I can't change its size ([you can see my attempt here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s90zD.png)). I also want to have a grid only on one cell, not the whole table (or document). Does anyone knows how something like that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the grid first by resizing columns and rows.
2. Merge cells on the left, above and below to form the other parts of your table.
3. Apply different thickness cell borders in the different parts of your table to get the effect you want.